# How to use php 'exec' to run .jar with input parameters

Tags: java, php, jar, command-line-arguments

I have a php file which runs a '.jar' file. Code is given bellow

```
exec("java -Xmx1g -jar \"C:\Users\Roxy\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Entity Extraction\dist\Entity Extraction.jar",$output);
```

This works fine without any error
But now I need to pass an array (lets say **$testArray**) with this command to 'Entity Extraction.jar' file and access it in my main method in java code.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

**Update:**

In my php file, I have

```
$testArr[0] = 'test1';
$testArr[1] = 'test2'; 

$str = "java -Xmx1g -jar \"C:\Users\Roxy\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Entity Extraction\dist\Entity Extraction.jar ";

foreach($testArr as $param){
 $str.=$param.' ';
}

exec($str,$output);
print_r($output);
```

In my java Main Class, I have

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int length = args.length;
     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          System.out.println(args[i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to just add the array to the exec command, provided it is composed of strings, and can then access it in your java main via the args parameter (it will show up as a single String which you'll have to split). However, could you elaborate where you're going with this? This kinda sounds like a bad thing to do in the first place...

Comment: can you please tell me how to use it in 'exec' code and use it in main method(if you can with an example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running a jar in the command line, every parameter you put after `Extraction.jar` separated by a space will automatically go into the args array.

So you need to run on the array and build the string you want to pass:

```
 $str = "java -Xmx1g -jar \"C:\Users\Roxy\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Entity Extraction\dist\Entity Extraction.jar ";

foreach($testArr as $param){
 $str.=$param.' ';
}

exec($str,$output);
```

This is assuming the array only contains strings or numbers. if it contains objects or other arrays, you need to manipulate this code a bit, but you get the idea.

Comment: This doesn't work. I add $testArr[0] = 'test1';$testArr[1] = 'test2'; before
'$str=....' argument. Add bellow command in my main method.
int length = args.length;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            System.out.println(args[i]);
}

Comment: Please update the question with the code you tried, its hard to see it in the comments.

Comment: I tried this with the command prompt also just by giving single string after the 'Extraction.jar '. But it says 'unable to access jarfile ...'

Comment: It works in the command prompt when I went into the 'dist' folder using cd command and then run the .jar file with a input parameter?

Comment: is your jar name "entity extraction.jar" with a space? if so that is a big no-no, change it to entity_extraction.jar and try again

Comment: also put the jar in a no space path like `c:`, spaces in the path cause problems a lot of time and usually it is good to avoid them

Comment: I cant put my jar file in a c: drive when I am hosting it right? So will there be a problem when I host it?

Comment: what do you mean by hosting it? and it doesn't have to be `c:`, as long as the path does not contain spaces.

Comment: I changed it. Now it doesn't have any spaces. Still doesn't work. But if I moved my entity_extraction.jar file to 'c:\User\Roshan>'(my default command prompt path) it works. But I need to run it at "C:\Users\Roxy\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Entity_Extraction\dist\entity_extraction.jar"

Comment: basically when you have spaces in the path you need to wrap it with "", so you'll run it like : `java -Xmx1g -jar "C:/Users/Roxy/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Entity Extraction/dist/entity_extraction.jar" test1`

Comment: yes,code you just gave me works in the command prompt. But how do I use this in my php file?

Comment: try: `$str =  'java -Xmx1g -jar "C:/Users/Roxy/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Entity Extraction/dist/entity_extraction.jar" test1'`

Comment: what do you get? try echoing the string before exceuting it and then run it in command line and see what error you get

Comment: You are a genius..! now it works, Many thanks for the help :) I can handle the rest

Answer (score 0):

you could pass `print_r($testArray,true);` or you could write a function that cycles through the array and creates a list.

Comment: how do I pass 'print_r($testArray,true);' with 'exec' ?

Comment: you can either do `exec("stuff here ".print_r($testArray,true)." other stuff here");` or pass it via a variable using `$params = print_r($testArray,true);`